# struct not keeping tuples order when passed (swift3)

Tags: ios, struct, swift3, uiviewcontroller, tuples

My Code produces a a tuples that is displayed on a label on view controller 1. I tried struct the label from vc1 to vc2 but the order is not being kept. All I want to do is replicate the exact order and the way the tuple is displayed on vc 1, on VC 2.

VIEW CONTROLLER 1

```
 import UIKit

var number = [Int]()
var yourArray = [String]()


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var labez: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textB: UITextField!

    @IBAction func move(_ sender: Any) {



        bad.mm = [String( labez.text ?? "")]


    }
    @IBAction func store(_ sender: Any) {

        yourArray.append((textA.text!))
        number.append(Int(textB.text!)!)
        let tuples = zip(yourArray,number)
        let sorted = tuples.sorted(by: { this, next in
            if this.0 < next.0 {
                return true
            } else if this.0 == next.0 {
                return this.1 < next.1
            } else {
                return false
            }
        })
        print(sorted)

        labez.text = sorted.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")
     bad.mm = [String(describing:  sorted.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")





            )]
    }
    struct bad {

static var mm = [String]()

      }
    }
```

[image]

view controller 2

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var benCarson: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    benCarson.text = (String(describing: ViewController.bad.mm))
}





}
```

[image]

Comment: If you add `print(bad.mm)` after `bad.mm.append(String(describing:  sorted.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")`  , see what does it print?

Comment: If the entry is a,2 in the log file it prints [" (\"a\", 2)"]

Comment: If there are more values , does it print the right order?

Comment: IF the entries are entered in order by this way a,2 a,1 this is what is printed in the log file [" (\"a\", 2)", " (\"a\", 1)\n (\"a\", 2)"]

Comment: But do you want it to print? I don't understand what you are trying to do. What should the string look like?

Comment: on vc2 the label should read (a,1), (a,2) just like in vc1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides my critique of how you designed your data and your naming conventions. I believe what you want is to *ASSIGN* your `bad.mm`instead of *APPEND*.

What is happening is the first time you enter values to `bad.mm` it is `(a, 2)`. Then when it is *appended* you add the sorted arrays `(a, 1), (a, 2)` to the existing string, making it `(a, 2), (a, 1), (a, 2)` If you assign it it will be now just the new, sorted array, `(a, 1), (a, 2)`.

To assign change

```
bad.mm.append(String(describing:  sorted.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n"))
```

In `ViewController` class to

```
bad.mm = String(describing:  sorted.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")
```

In `ViewController` your `move` function does a similar thing where it `APPENDS` to `bad.mm` where you probably want to assign. However you assign it with a `UITextField.Text` property which is optional. Using the `??` operator you can give unwrap this optional while providing it a default value. An empty string is often a good default value. So for this I would suggest changing the line inside of `@IBAction func move` to the following:

```
bad.mm = labez.text ?? ""
```

Or just actually delete this line since you assign bad.mm and labez.text at the same time in your earlier function. But that is why you were getting the `optional()` around your text.

That should give you your desired effect. The reason your "tuple" isn't being passed in the right order is that your not grabbing the sorted tuple from one VC to the next, you are grabbing an improperly formatted string from one VC to another. Consider passing the sorted tuple directly and then formatting the string separately in both `ViewControllers` to reduce confusion.

Comment: This is close! However the vc2 is formatted in a way that for whatever reasons optionals are displayed. If you can just tell me a way to remove those optionals I can award you the bounty. I edited my question with your code suggestion and change vc 2 picture.

Comment: In your `move` function you have the same thing where you need to *APPEND* `bad.mm`, but you append it  with `labez.text` which is optional. I would change that line to `bad.mm = labez.text ?? ""` I'll change my answer to include this.

Comment: Closer! I followed your suggestions if I could just get the [] and n out of vc 2 and thats it.Thank You So much!

Comment: Ok you got it! To get that removed [n] in vc2 i had to put      benCarson.text = ViewController.bad.mm.map { " \($0)" }.joined(separator:"\n")
. In the vc2 thats it. Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `prepare(for segue:` instead of a struct to pass the tuples.

You can do it like this:
In ViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // give your segue an id (in the interface builder)
    if segue.identifier == "mySegue" , 
       let nextScene = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
       nextScene.yourTuples = yourArray // or anything else
    } 

}
```

And in your ViewController2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

val yourTuples: [String]()!

@IBOutlet var benCarson: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    benCarson.text = (String(describing: ViewController.bad.mm))
}

}
```

Comment: I want the data to be passed even if the user does not go to vc 2. So for example the user goes from vc 1 to vc 3, then from vc 3 to vc 2 the data will still be passed.